# How to use multiple objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm using tkinter to generate a maze but the thing is that I used blocks for the walls, I'm still a beginner in python so I don't know how I'm supposed to do this, here is the problem : 
To have a block I used 
`block = PhotoImage(file  ='images/block.ppm')`

```
block0 = Label(root, image=block)
block1 = Label(root, image=block)
...
```

I used a script to write me like 425 objects and place them at different places with `block0.place(x=20, y=20)`, I knew it was dumb but I had no idea what to do else, it printed me the maze but when I wanted to close with the command root.destroy
I couldn't make it. I guess it's because I did this dumb thing.
So how am I supposed to make this ?
I tried to learn more about classes but it didn't worked too.
Here is my code https://mega.nz/#F!Z7xB2IJK!NSSLM6rRFJDE5kpMPs6W_Q
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you `root.destroy` instead of `root.destroy()` ? One thing looks unrelated to the other...

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: What are you trying to do? [2]

Comment: @Pygasm To make my maze I have to use many 'blocks' images to do the walls, I need 425 blocks so I was wondering how to make all those blocks whitout having to call 425 times : 'block[insertnumber] = Label(root, image=block). So how am I supposed to do this ?

Comment: @Prune Maybe I could put all my code online ?

Comment: You can use lists: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Please do, we cannot answer if you dont share code.

Comment: We don't need/want to see _all_ your code, just a minimal amount which illustrates the problem(s) (including your own attempts, if any, to fix it/them).

Comment: https://mega.nz/#F!Z7xB2IJK!NSSLM6rRFJDE5kpMPs6W_Q

Comment: `for i in range(425): blocks.append(Label(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me quite some time to figure out what you want to do. If you haven't found a solution to your problem yet, here is some code to try out.

The first thing you should do is declare a global variable to store all maze blocks.

```
blocks = [] # create a list for the maze blocks
```

Then we will need to functions for building and destroying the maze. You already have a similar structure in your code example (`destroythemhehe` and `mazebuilder`) but we can greatly improve readability and performance here.

```
def gamephase():
    global menu, quit, block
    menu = Button(root, text='Menu', relief=RIDGE, bg='#C90', command=menuevent)
    menu.place(x=50, y=540)
    quit = Button(root, text='Quitter', relief=RIDGE, bg='#C90', command=destroy_maze)
    quit.place(x=670, y=540)
    generate = Button(root, text='Generer', relief=RIDGE, bg='#C90', command=build_maze)
    generate.place(x=360, y=540)
```

The function for building the maze is not really complicated:

```
def build_maze():
    global blocks
    for x in range(17):
        for y in range(25):
            if zone[x][y]:
                b = Label(root, image=block)
                b.place(x=20 + y * 30, y=20 + x * 30) # a formula which calculates the position of the block
                blocks.append(b) # add the block to the list
```

It does basically the same thing as your function `mazebuilder` but it saves all the `Label`s to the `blocks` list which is much cleaner than your `blocker` function. Now we need a function to destroy the blocks:

```
def destroy_maze():
    global blocks
    for x in blocks: # destroy each block
        x.destroy()
    blocks = []
```

And we are done! This should work as expected but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

You can make your code even prettier if you use classes instead of global variables. This can also help you prevent some nasty bugs.

Comment: Thank you a lot !!! I'm sorry I didn't saw your message earlier and sorry for the variable and function names that are in french or named in a dumb way because it's how I code hahahaha, but thank you a lot, I didn't thinked about putting the blocks in a list, it sounded weird to me to put variables into a list. Anyway thank you a lot again, it started to get better and I think I might finish this school project !